# Deploy a custom UI5 library in SAP BAS

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, ui5-tooling, sap-business-application-studio

I need to build some custom Fiori libraries with SAPUI5.

On the internet, I found many tutorials about how to build such libraries but no tutorial shows how I can deploy it. The only tutorials I found about the deployment are using the old Web IDE but we're using the SAP BAS (SAP Business Application Studio) which doesn't have those functions.

So then I learned about how SAP handles the custom libraries and tried to deploy it like a normal Fiori app by creating a `ui5-deploy.yaml`:

```yaml
specVersion: '2.5'
metadata:
  name: 'zcalibtest'
type: library
builder:
  resources:
    excludes:
      - /test/**
      - /localService/**
  customTasks:
    - name: deploy-to-abap
      afterTask: generateCachebusterInfo
      configuration:
        target:
          destination: {DESTINATION}
          url: {URL}
        credentials:
          username: env:DEPLOY_USERNAME
          password: env:DEPLOY_PASSWORD
        app:
          name: Z_CA_LIB_TEST
          package: ZCA_TEST
          transport: {TRANSPORT}
```

... and running the following NPM `"deploy"` script:

```bash
npm run build && fiori deploy -y --config ui5-deploy.yaml && rimraf archive.zip
```

But that gives me the following error:

> sh: 1: fiori: not found

So I think that's not the way to go. But how can I do this? I couldn't be the only person on the planet that is using SAP BAS and tries to deploy a custom library.

Edit:

My `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "zcalibtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ui5/cli": "^2.9.3",
    "@sap/ux-ui5-tooling": "^1.5.5",
    "karma": "^6.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-ui5": "^2.3.3",
    "ui5-middleware-livereload": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "ui5": {
    "dependencies": [
      "ui5-middleware-livereload"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ui5 build --clean-dest",
    "deploy": "npm run build && fiori deploy -y --config ui5-deploy.yaml && rimraf archive.zip",
    "start": "ui5 serve --open test-resources/path/to/lib/zcalibtest/Example.html",
    "testsuite": "ui5 serve --open test-resources/path/to/lib/zcalibtest/qunit/testsuite.qunit.html",
    "test": "karma start --browsers=ChromeHeadless --singleRun=true"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

Comment: Which environment are you targeting? SAP BTP Cloud Foundry env? SAP BTP ABAP env? ABAP on-premise? SAP HANA Cloud ...?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann We're using the on premise solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the deploy part: you need to add the package `"@sap/ux-ui5-tooling"` (**both** in your `devDependencies` and in your ui5 `dependencies`) and `rimraf` (only in your `devDependencies`).

For the build part: build steps for libraries are slightly different so yours should be similar to these (maybe you don't need all the steps..). For the building part you need to add only `bestzip` to your  `devDependencies` I guess

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && ui5 build --include-task=generateManifestBundle generateCachebusterInfo && npm run flatten && npm run clean-after-flatten && npm run zip",
    "zip": "cd dist && npx bestzip ../ExampleLibrary-content.zip *",
    "flatten": "cp -r dist/resources/name/space/examplelibrary/* dist && cp dist/resources/name/space/examplelibrary/.library dist ",
    "clean": "npx rimraf ExampleLibrary-content.zip dist",
    "clean-after-flatten": "rm -rf dist/resources dist/test-resources"
}
```

You can find more info about building libraries in [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/10/16/using-ui5-libraries-in-cf-approuter/) blog post from the SAP Community.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify: To use a library I need to copy it to every projects mta/project folder that the app can use it? I thought you just need to add it to the mainfest and that's it. Otherwise would be a horrible way.

Comment: I don't think I get your question right... I'm not well versed in mta application development but usually, when you  deploy a library, there is a way to route your requests to the deployed version of the library, no need to copy it everywhere :-)

Comment: So the build part works. I'm able to create the zip out of my library. But the question is now where and how do I need to deploy the zip to use it in my flp applications?

Comment: Deploying a library in your gateway is the same as deploying an application, you can configure your deployment via the ui5-deploy.yaml. The BAS can drive you through this process with the wizard. This is a different question, though!

Comment: In the original question I mentioned that I don't understand the build process and the deployment and the title is "Deploy a custom UI5 library in SAP BAS" so I don't understand why this should be a different question? Can't find an example for the `deploy-yaml` of a library and don't understand why I need to make a zip file out of the library when I'm deploying the lib like an application..

Comment: Ok, I misinterpreted your question... I mean, I thought the deploy of the library  was only a technical issue, not a logical one (or both).

Comment: Anyway... As I told you in my answer, not all buildings steps are relevant 'cause some of them depend on your landscape (I think zipping the library is relevant only in CF). Your ui-deploy.yaml  is totally fine. After deployment you need to route your app calls to the library depending on the system where you deployed your library (approuter, resourceroots property or neo-app.json, for example).